# Is there anyway in Idea to recognize a getter/setter generated by lombok in the same module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

[image: intellj error]So looking at my class files the getters/setters are being generated just fine, but I'm trying to write a copy method that looks like this in the same jar.

```
@Data
public class SoftwareVersions {
    private String applicationVersion;

    void copyTo( MonitorFoleyConnection mfc ) {
        mfc.setApplicationVersion( applicationVersion );
    }
}
```

in gradle

```
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.+")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.+")
```

[image: annotation processor settings]

is it possible to get intellij to recognize the existance of this method?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "recognize the existence of this method"? What are you exactly trying to do? And that method is package-private and will adhere to the rules of the package-private access property.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal intellij does not believe the setter exists, so it won't autocomplete, highlights as a missing method... it does compile, attaching a screenshot

Comment: Do you have the Lombok plugin for IntelliJ installed?

Comment: Do you have the Lombok plugin installed in your IntelliJ installation?  I'm guessing you don't, because I love Lombok and I've never had this issue.  The plugin is absolutely needed to remain sane while using Lombok in IntelliJ.

Comment: no, I didn't know there was a plugin

Comment: @xenoterracide you need to look install the Lombok plugin for IntelliJ, it's there in Plugin marketplace. Simply search for Lombok and you'll get it in the first result.

Comment: yep, that fixes it

Comment: @xenoterracide also, get the latest dependencies for Lombok `compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10"` and place them at the top of your `dependencies` list in `build.gradle` because sometimes there are other annotation processors that generate code before Lombok does and you end up getting "method not found"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have. You just need to do two things:

1. Install the Lombok Plugin for Intellij:

[image: Lombok Plugin]

2. Enable the annotation processing:

[image: Annotation Processing]